# Read input from Runtime().exec with Non-block I/O

Tags: java, android

It seems that using `BufferedReader` to read a process's `InputStream`
will somehow result in a block I/O behavior.
And the effect is like the program doesn't get the instant input from the process.
I know there are more lines that could be read at that time, but the `BufferedReader`
just keep waiting for sometime then I can finally get the lines updated.

Here is the code:

```
While((str=bufferedReader.readLine()!=null) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
```

Is there some kinds of method that can keep reading from the process without blocking
in the while() condition? cause the process won't return null or anything....

Answer (score 0):

You can read the child process output in a separate thread. Something like this

```
static BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
    final BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (String line; (line = rdr.readLine()) != null;) {
                    queue.put(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    for (;;) {
        String line = queue.poll();
        if (line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        } else if (!t.isAlive()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide further information?
What does "child process" means?
And by using the separate thread am I still getting the right sequence of input? cause the sequence of the input will be important...

Comment: Added a non-blocking example

Comment: Dude, I think this will help!!!
I am testing with your sample....
Hope it will works, thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you come up with this solutions?
Did this related to your work???
I can't finish modifying my code cause I got to catch a train.
Anyway, I will test it completely and with your support.
I think it can be done. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) library for non-blocking I/O to external processes.  Consider it a replacement for `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` in Java.